# Concat sql result in one row Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm usung Oracle 10.
I've to concat the results from two sql queries in one row.

**The first query is :**

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.comments from flight F, task WHERE F.id = task.flight_id and task.name like 'BO%' AND F.comments IS NOT NULL
```

Which returns :

> Initial comment.

**And the second query (it concats the result one the query in one row) :**

```
SELECT (RTRIM(XMLAGG(xmlelement(X, T.comments||',')order by F.id).extract('//text()'),',')) list from  flight F, task T  where F.id = T.flight_id and T.name like 'BOS%' AND T.comments IS NOT NULL
```

Which returns :

> First comment.,Second comment.,Third comment.

I have to concat the results into one row so I did :

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.comments from flight F, task WHERE F.id = task.flight_id and task.name like 'BO%' AND F.comments IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT (RTRIM(XMLAGG(xmlelement(X, T.comments||',')order by F.id).extract('//text()'),',')) list from  flight F, task T  where F.id = T.flight_id and T.name like 'BOS%' AND T.comments IS NOT NULL
```

Which returns me two rows. The first one about the result of the first query and the second one about the second query.

I would like to retrieve them in one row like :

> Initial comment.First comment.,Second comment.,Third comment.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push the two queries into a single subquery in the correct order then apply your xmlagg over top. Something like:

```
SELECT (RTRIM(XMLAGG(xmlelement(X, comments||',')order by sortorder, F.id).extract('//text()'),',')) list
from ( 
SELECT DISTINCT  1 sortorder, 
       f.id,
       F.comments 
  from flight F, task 
  WHERE F.id = task.flight_id 
  and task.name like 'BO%' 
  AND F.comments IS NOT NULL
union all  
SELECT 2, f.id, T.comments 
  from  flight F, task T  
 where F.id = T.flight_id 
 and T.name like 'BOS%' 
 AND T.comments IS NOT NULL  )
```

(pls forgive any minor syntax glitches - I'm away from my database at the moment)

Comment: That's so great... It is working fine ! Thank you :)